# Magento - Show Custom Attributes in Grouped Product table

Tags: php, magento, custom-attributes

I need to find a way to show the value of a custom attribute in place of the "Product Name" shown in the image below.

[image: Grouped products table]
<sub>(source: [magentocommerce.com](http://www.magentocommerce.com/images/uploads/grouped_prod_front.gif))</sub>

I'm working with /app/design/frontend/default/defaultx/template/catalog/product/view/type/grouped.php

The code below doesn't work(the custom attribute is yearmade):

```
<?php if (count($_associatedProducts)): ?>  
<?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>  
    <tr>  
        <td><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getYearmade()) ?></td>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: So the answer turned out to be quite simple. You see what I failed to mention above was that there *was* indeed output... but that it was just a number (eg: 52). Turns out this was the ID for that custom attribute value (It was a Dropdown type of custom attribute).

So in summary
This works for custom attributes of type text:

```
echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getYearmade())
```

But for all other types of custom attribute (I think), the following should be used:

```
echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getAttributeText('yearmade'))
```

I would not have discovered this without the most excellent answer provided by Alan Storm, below. Thank you sir.

Comment: To those still providing answers, note that this question was posted 3yrs ago. The Magento codebase has evolved since then, so obviously your results will be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Magento models have a "getData" method available, which will return an php-array of key/value pairs.  Try this at the top of your grouped.phtml file (after $_product is defined)

```
print('<pre>');print_r($_product->getData());print('</pre>');
```

You should see output that looks something like the following.

```
Array
(
    [store_id] => 1
    [entity_id] => 3437
    [entity_type_id] => 4
    [attribute_set_id] => 27
    [type_id] => grouped
    [sku] => 
    [category_ids] => 
    [created_at] => 2009-04-16 03:37:51
...
```

So, you can grab an array of properties and just pull the key out. You could also use Magento's convenience/magic getX and setX methods.  On all Magento models, you can access any property in the data array by calling a method based on the camel case version of the name,

```
$created_at = $_product->getCreatedAt();
$_product->setCreatedAt($date);
```

So, whatever your custom attribute name is, you should be able to get at it using the above, and if you're not sure just print_r or var_dump the contents of the array returned by getData().

Finally, if the custom attribute is on one of the related products simple product, you'll wants something more like

```
$_associatedProducts[0]->getCreatedAt();
```

Comment: I can't seem to get custom attributes with the code above. I'm I doing something wrong? I have a custom category called "product_type" and I would like to show it's value on the grouped.phtml page.

Comment: How are you creating the product object?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

1. You must locate grouped.phtml
   `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml`
2. Get the item, example
   `$_item[units]`
3. Add a cell into the table and paste echo `$_item['units'];`
4. Thats all :)

Answer (score 0):

From ver. 1.3. and in 1.4 too you must use **$_item** not **$_product**, for me this works fine in groupable table too.

Example:

```
<?php echo $_item->getAttributeText('your attribute'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins that can solve your solution really easily. You can find the plugin here that takes product options and displays them in a grid: http://www.magemechanics.com/product-grid-options.html