# is it possible to show custom attributes of associated products under a grouped product in front end? (Magento)

Tags: magento

I have a typical condition in my magento Grouped product. 
Is it possible to show Custom attribute (color dropdown) of associated product under Grouped products in the fronted.. as shown below

Consider the sample blanket product

[image: Consider the sample]

Let me know if i am not clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear your question but I would give you a small example to get text field, multiple select or drop-down listbox value.

First, we should load the product collection :

```
<?php
   // load the product that id 125, then show attributes of the product
   $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProduct()->getId(125));
   echo $product->getCustomAttribute();

   // lets say your custom attributes name is "size" and type is text field
   echo $product->getSize();

   // lets assume your custom attributes name is "product_size then
   echo $product->getProductSize();

   // lets assume your attribute type is drop-down, this will get array of attribute options instead of value that you selected
   echo $product->getAttributeText(product_size);

   // to get drop-down value that you selected
   $attribute = $product->getAttributes();
   $productSize = $attribute['product_size']->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

let me know if it's not meet your request.

Comment: Thanks Oğuz Çelikdemir... i will try to use this code to get the custom attributes..
But, when user selects a specific color in the drop down and add the product to cart.. will the selected color info stored in the shopping cart? or i have to further customize this to achieve it..?

Comment: @balanv sure, you should customize the code to see attributes in the shopping cart. I have a small sample but I should look where it is.

Comment: @balanv check this link please [Display All Product Attribute in Mageto Shopping Cart](http://magentosnippet.blogspot.com/2011/06/display-all-product-attribute-in-mageto.html)

Comment: and this is the important, thanks to @tmilhouse [Accessing Custom Product Attributes in the Cart/Checkout Area](http://www.brimllc.com/2011/04/magento-accessing-custom-product-attributes-in-the-cartcheckout-area/)

Comment: When i create a custom attribute for an associated product under a grouped product... the associated product for which i created the custom attribute disappears from the front end... did magento by default prevents products with custom attribute be shown under a grouped product..??

Comment: check this topic as well [All Addtional Attributes for Grouped Products](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972379/all-addtional-attributes-for-grouped-products-in-magento)

Comment: and, check associated product stock status, they should "in stock" status and re-generate index and clean the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this, 3 edited files.
But these files are edited for a previous version of Magento, I don't know which version.
I have uploaded this 3 files on my Magento 1.7 and it works but when add the product to the cart it give's a error with `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php`

This file: Quote.php is one of the edited files, when i upload the original Quote.php it works.

Look at this pic: http://s8.postimage.org/g8bvbth0z/Naamloos.png

But maybe i get more errors in the future, i don't have any ideas..

I am a noob with this, if someone can look at the edited files and chek how they have do this and compare this with the newest files for Magento 1.7 maybe we can help to many peoples with this problem.