# Magento: How to collect all products from a category that have x attribute

Tags: magento

i need to create my own list.phtml from scratch and i need to display products from a certain category that will have "x" attribute.
I have read a lot and play with the current getLoadedProductCollection() ?> in list.phtml but i cannot make it work.

Any advise?

Edit:
Ok i was able to show all products from a category using this code: http://blog.decryptweb.com/category-products-magento/

Now how i will to filter the color as well in the $collection?

Edit2: by using this code ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like' => 'UX%')) i did manage to display only products contain this SKU
But when i try with color it doesnt show any products.
My color attribute is multiple select. and i set the code to ('color', array('like' => 'black'))
Also the layered navigation will not work?
And the toolbar is not correct, it will allways display all products and it says "1 product"

Thanks in advance

Comment: check my latest answer [Show custom attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754579/is-it-possible-to-show-custom-attributes-of-associated-products-under-a-grouped/8763770#8763770)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could have debugged this.  The first is to look at the SQL that the collection is using to query the database, with:

```
echo $collection->getSelect()->assemble();
```

The second is to find the value of the `colour` attribute from the data array of your product, like:

```
var_dump($collection->getFirst()->getData('colour'));
```

In both of these cases you would have found that the attribute is stored in the database as an integer.  In order to query the collection for an attribute that is stored in a select, multi-select, or similar, you'll always need to us the integer that represents the option, not the attribute label.

Comment: Hi Nick and thanks for your reply, after long of research i start to understand how the collection works <br> However now i have another problem, the sorting.<br>I use my modified version of list.phtml to display products with some attributes but i need allways to sort them as New.<br> If you change the sort from the normal list.phtml catalog, the sorting will affect also my modified home_list.phtml. How can i force it to sort allways the new?

Comment: I found this snipshet for clear the collection :$_productCollection->clear()->setPageSize(6) and it works really good. How can i force also the cleared collection to sort by newest?This ->addAttributeToSort('new_from_date','desc') does not work :(