# Display newly added simple attributes in product page and show the selected values in shopping cart (Magento)

Tags: magento

I have two variations in my website color and size. I have added it to my "Default Attribute Set" and updated respective color and size for each product.

But now i need to display the color and size option in a drop down box, and when user selects it and adds the product to cart. It should appear in the shopping cart along with product information and in the entire checkout process.

is there any option in backend to enable this? or should i do this by modifying the code?

if i should do it by modify the code, how do i do it?

(I learnt ways to show the attribtues in drop down in product page through the link [is it possible to show custom attributes of associated products under a grouped product in front end? (Magento)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754579/is-it-possible-to-show-custom-attributes-of-associated-products-under-a-grouped), but not sure with showing them in cart page)

please suggest.

Thanks,

Balan

Comment: Are you looking to just show selected attribute or you want to edit in shopping cart page.

Comment: i want to show the selected attributes of a product in shopping cart..

Comment: This will normally work with Magento default.What product type you are using

Comment: I am using only simple products. In my case, i just need the color and size drop down to appear in the product page and based on the selection it should appear in shopping cart.. i know i could use Custom options under each simple product.. but not sure if thats correct.. so i am trying to add color and size to attribute set.. and show it in product page..
(Note : There will be no price change when user selects any of the option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code in your catalog/product/view.phtml page.That will bring the custom options to your product page.

```
   if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):
        echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) 
   endif;       

    if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):
      echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) 
    endif;
```

### Shopping cart

check you checkout.xml for addItemRender methods are added or not in checkout.cart block.

```
 <checkout_cart_index translate="label">
  <reference name="content">
     <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
....
<action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
...
     </block>
  </reference>
```

and check template files is it called correctly or not.

Check with magento default is your blocks are called correctly in cart.phtml and other pages

Comment: actually i achieved bringing custom options to product page... but stuck with showing selected attribute in the shopping cart and entire checkout process.. do i have to customize it fully to do this?

Comment: the code added in view.phtml throws an error like `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/content/16/8165716/html/dev/app/design/frontend/default/boho/template/catalog/product/view.phtml on line 223`

Comment: Check your opening and closing tags

Answer (score 0):

balanv,
Use "Configurable" products.
It will provide you dropdown with colors on product page
And will display selected colors in checkout cart.
Read magento wiki for more details ;)

Comment: Welcome to magento logic.
Anyway its much easier then customizing existing logic.