# How to get the category list in magento?

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system

I am newbie to magento.We are using **magento 1.6**.One of my friend did the designing part for magento.Currently we have the static categories on the right side by using 2column-right.phtml.

No I want to display the active categories in the right column.I tried all the solutions mentioned in the post 
[Stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604743/how-to-get-a-category-listing-from-magento) .Tried accepted and unaccepted solutions too.Also tried some others but no luck.whether I am in the right way.

1.Is this the proper way to get the categories in the 2column-right.phtml.
   2.If not  how can I get the categories.
   3. What I need to change to get the category list from the above solutions.
Please give me solution for this .

Comment: Your question is now nearly a year old. How did you solve your problem? What is your answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

In the below link, they guide to create vertical menu. 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/navigation/how_to_create_a_vertical_left_hand_menu

or

Use the below free extension to install the vertical menu.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/vertical-sidebar-menu.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to do two things:

1) Go to admin Catalog -> categories , select a category and check whether the desired category **is enabled and is Anchor is set to Yes**.

2) Call this file where you want to show your categories "**app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/catalog/navigation/lef.phtml**"

you may need to do a lil adjustments.